# Transition upon clicking "scroll" arrow

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have been working on this website for a while now and I came upon an issue that I have just recently noticed. If you run the code below, you will find a scroll arrow that will be clickable to lead you to the next section. However, upon this click, the section is immediately transferred. I would like to be able to click that and I am scrolled down smoothly. I did this effect before, by accident, and I have not been able to figure out what I did. If someone could show me how,I would appreciate it.

Thank you,
John

```css
#section01 {
  background: url(http://wallpapercave.com/wp/LekAYO3.jpg) center center / cover no-repeat;
}
#section02 {
  background: url(http://wallpapercave.com/wp/8iAP1eI.jpg) center center / cover no-repeat;
}
.arrow a {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 50px;
  left: 50%;
  z-index: 8;
  display: inline-block;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  color: #fff;
  font: normal 400 20px/1'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  letter-spacing: .1em;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: opacity .3s;
}
/*
 .arrow a:hover {
  opacity: .5;
 }
 */

#section01 a,
#section02 a,
#section03 a,
#section03 a,
#section04 a,
#section05 a,
#section06 a {
  padding-top: 60px;
}
/* WHITE ARROW */

#section01 a span,
#section04 a span,
#section05 a span,
#section06 a span {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  margin-left: -12px;
  border-left: 1px solid #fff;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -webkit-animation: sdb01 2s infinite;
  animation: sdb01 2s infinite;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
/* BLACK ARROW */

#section02 a span,
#section03 a span,
#section03 a span {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  margin-left: -12px;
  border-left: 1px solid black;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -webkit-animation: sdb01 2s infinite;
  animation: sdb01 2s infinite;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
@-webkit-keyframes sdb01 {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(0, 0);
  }
  20% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-10px, 10px);
  }
  40% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(0, 0);
  }
}
@keyframes sdb01 {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(0, 0);
  }
  20% {
    transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-10px, 10px);
  }
  40% {
    transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(0, 0);
  }
}
```

```html
<section id="section01" class="arrow" style="background-attachment: fixed;">

  <h1 class="main">Welcome</h1> 
  <h5 class="main"> <br> <br> <br> <br> A Website by John Ta </h5>
  <a href="#section02"><span></span>Scroll</a>

</section>

<!--  END SECTION01 -->

<section id="section02" class="arrow" style="background-attachment: fixed;">
  <h3 class="main" style="color: black;
   ">Filler?</h3> 
  <h5 class="main" style="color: black;"> <br> <br> <br> <br> Filler</h5>
  <a href="#section03" style="color: black;"><span></span>Scroll</a>
</section>

<!--  END SECTION02 -->
```

Comment: where's your javascript? Also, putting everything in a codepen or jsfiddle and drawing attention to only the most relevant pieces of code in your question (the arrow, click listener, and animation code) is a much better practice and will get you more answers

Comment: There was no javascript used

Comment: Please do not use the code provided, as it is messed up because I had to take it from my main code. You can look at it to get an idea of what is going on, but it does not display exactly what I want.

Answer (score 1):

Jumping between `#anchors` is handled by the browser itself and not CSS transitions, so unless you're looking for a creative (and probably somewhat messy) workaround involving container elements and absolute positioning, the only way to affect browser scrolling is going to be with JavaScript.

There are some existing libraries that you could use, like Chris Ferdinandi’s [smooth-scroll](https://github.com/cferdinandi/smooth-scroll), or you could try writing your own with some [help](https://www.sitepoint.com/smooth-scrolling-vanilla-javascript/).